# Is it feasible to break Diffie-Hellman key exchange when the implementation uses a poor-quality PRNG?

Tags: random-number-generator, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I've come across an implementation of DH in Java that uses the `Random` class to generate the secret integer value $a$, as shown in in [Wikipedia's description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Description) of the algorithm. As such, the seed of the RNG is only 32 bits and the output may be predictable.

By observing DH exchanges only, would it be possible to predict or compute the shared secret?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An attack would be trivial if the seed of the RNG was only 32 bits; just enumerate the seeds, and test which matches the intercepted messages. That's easy.

However the default Java `Random` class uses a 48-bit state and seed (which would still be attackable, though $2^{16}$ times less easily), and there are safe subclasses, thus use of `Random` does not imply an (insecure) 48-bit state, if the object really is a `SecureRandom`. See this [Java 1.4.2 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) or this [Java (1.)7.x one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29).

Update: While it seems the seed of the default Java `Random` class is 48-bit, its default seed indeed is 32-bit on some old Java platforms, and predictable to some degree on top of that; it is 48-bit on the latest Java platforms, and seems less predictable (though it could still be predictable/repeatable in a virtualized context).

Comment: @HenrickHellström According to the docs, it looks like the [`setSeed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed%28long%29) method (as called by the constructor) uses all 48 bits. However, the default seed in pre-Java7 is simply the current time as a millisecond-resolution value.

Comment: @HenrickHellström: the initialization for the default RNG was improved, and is now using `seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime()`; search for that.

Comment: Correction: the seed was the system time in milliseconds on Java 1.4.2 and earlier.

Comment: There are at least three different implementations of the default seed for the default Java `Random` class; one use an at-most-32-bit seed derived from the system time in millisecond (OR MORE); another use an at-most-48-bit seed of `++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()` where `seedUniquifier` is some shared global initialized from a public constant; the third uses `seedUniquifier()^System.nanoTime()` where `seedUniquifier()` uses a shared global atomically updated per a multiplicative RNG with public seed and multiplier. Neither method is meant to be used for crypto.